# Blend mode "Add" in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

Does illustrator have the equivalent of an "Add" blend mode? This would mean that

(R=0, G=128, B=255) + (R=255, G=128, B=0) = **white**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent of Add/Subtract or Linear Dodge/Burn in AI, unfortunately. Using "Lighten" can sometimes get you there, but in almost all cases requires a third layer, set to  Lighten or Color Dodge, to "fill in" the remaining channel.

Comment: That's odd! Why is that? And what exactly does "Lighten" do?

Comment: As to why, you'd have to ask the Illustrator team. :-) Lighten works on a channel-by-channel basis, and uses the lighter of the two values for each channel.

Comment: Ah, so it's like a per-channel "max". Thanks!